# Creating a vector in a method and setting it to a variable

Tags: c++, vector, reference, eclipse-cdt

OK so I an new to C++ and am fairly sure this should be a simple question if I can ask it right. Basically this is what I need to work:

```
printInfoFromVector(this->mycontroller.createVector)
```

This is the actual code I have:

```
vector<GasStation>& highPrices = this->myController.findHighestPrice();
    this->findPrice(highPrices);

vector<GasStation>& findHighestPrice(){
```

The problem that I am having is that I can not get they types of highPrices and findHighestPrice() to match. Im fairly sure the problem is because I am passing by ref but I pretty sure that the right way to do it.

Can anyone tell me the correct way to write the assignment statement and the method head so that the types match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `findHighestPrice` is computing a new vector, then you should not return a reference, but an actual vector. Thus you would have:

```
vector<GasStation> findHighestPrice() { ... }
vector<GasStation> highPrices = this->myController.findHighestPrice();
```

For example, if you defined `findHighestPrice` as

```
vector<GasStation>& findHighestPrice() {
  vector<GasStation> stations;
  // ...
  return stations;
}
```

then `stations` will be deallocated when the function returns and `highPrices` will be undefined.

Comment: Thank you. I had tried that but id didn't work. But I just found that it was because of errors elsewhere in my project. I think I have it working now